# Problem with incrementing a value in a for-loop

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a cell reference dynamic. Which means it has to include a variable which counts upwards. However, when I try to increment my counter, the "new" number is just added to the back of the old number.

I have done some basic programming in other languages, so I know the syntax of a for loop and how to increase the counter. But it doesn't seem to work as I wanted in AppScript.

```
function myFunction() {

  var counter = ["hello", "Bye"];;
  for (var i in counter)
  {
    Logger.log("Increment: " +Number(i+1));

  }
}
```

This gives me the following result: 
Increment: 1
Increment: 11
My expected result is: 
Increment: 1
Increment: 2

```
var mailList = sheet.getRange("C"+(i+1)).getValue();
```

The second example is from my code, and how I want it to work.
This line should make a variable that gets the value of the current cell in column c, plus index 1 because variable "i" start to get values from row number 2. Then it stores this result in a variable which I use to determine the receiver of the email, later on in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable i is not a number but a string, which causes this behaviour. "1" + "1" = "11".

```
var counter = ["hello", "Bye"];
for (var i in counter) {
    Logger.log(parseInt(i)+1);
}
```

Comment: Perfect @Marc. Just out of curiosity, why is this variable set as default string. Do I always need to add "parseInt" when I want to perform mathematical expression on a variable?

Comment: @VegardSmith-Johansen Because someone at google decided that is how it should work. No not always, it depends on what the variable is. You could for example do the same thing without typing like this: for (var i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) { Logger.log(i + 1); }